# How can I apply a CSS style to all elements with the .btn:hover pseudo-class that don't have the class '.dropdown-toggle'

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

I want to set a style on all my .btn elements that have the :hover pseudoclass, except for those elements which also have the .dropdown-toggle class. I tried a few different ways to do this:

attempt 1:

```
.btn:not(.dropdown-toggle):hover {
   background-color: inherit;
}
```

This didn't work. It's applying the :hover style both when hovering and when clicking the buttons

attempt 2:

```
div:not(.dropdown) > .btn:hover {
   background-color: inherit;
}
```

I really thought this one would work, but it's doing the same thing as above.

Update: Ok I was wrong about what was going on. I'm starting to see what's happening now. When the user clicks the button, then it has both :active and :hover on it at the same time. And normally the :active style takes precedence over the :hover style. However because my selector for the :hover style is more specific than that for :active, it's causing it to show the :hover style even when the button is clicked and ignore the :active style. Something like that?

Below is the example code. Expected behaviour: the background of the 'Regular button' should turn light blue when clicked. Actual behaviour: It just shows the :hover background-color red instead. Unless you click on the button and drag the mouse off it so that it's clicked but not hovered, then it shows the :active color properly.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="application.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Regular button</button>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown button</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">List item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

application.css

```
.btn:not(.dropdown-toggle):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the JFiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/29u643Lr/21/
```

Comment: It's something to do with which style takes precedence out of :active and :hover when a button is clicked. The more specific selector I'm using due to the :not part is causing the :active style (for when the button is clicked) to get overriden by the :hover style

Comment: Please put enough code into your question (not on an external site) to demonstrate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I may have found a solution using the :where() specificity-adjustment pseudo-class which reduces the specificity of everything in the brackets to 0. This way my :hover style isn't overriding :active, :disabled, :focus etc

```
.btn:where(:not(.dropdown-toggle)):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Update: Because I was still having problems where my .btn:hover selector was overriding the other selectors in bootstrap like :focus-visible, .active, .show, .disabled and :disabled. I've changed to a different method. Now I'm doing this:

```
.btn:hover 
{
  --bs-btn-hover-color: var(--bs-btn-color);
  --bs-btn-hover-bg: var(--bs-btn-bg);
}
```

I.e. I'm just overriding the bs variables that control the colour rather than overrding the styles themselves. In this way the order of precedence for the bootstrap button states remain unchanged.

Comment: do you need the `where()` at all? it should work without it.

Comment: the style on :active should take precedence over :hover.  I.e. if you click a button, you should see the :active style not the :hover style. Bootstrap is setting its own order of precedence based on the specificity of the pseudo-classes somehow. Adding :not(.dropdown-toggle) in seemed to be increasing the specificity of :hover beyond all the other classes like :active causing their styles not to show when hovering.

Comment: I realised this solution is still not clean. By setting .btn:hover it's still causing that style to override all of the styles defined after :hover in the bootstrap.css with the same specificity, in particular: :focus-visible, .active, .show, .disabled and :disabled. I'm not sure there is any way to neatly override bootstrap btn styles without causing a specificity mess.

Comment: This is pretty much why I stopped using css framworks. You should be able to just add `!important` to your basic rule(s) to override it.